# Find $k\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall{n}\in\mathbb{N}:\ln (n)=n^k$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I am trying to find a real number $k$ such that $\ln(n)=n^k$.

I know it is a number between $\frac{1}{e}$ and $\frac{1}{2e}$ but I am not sure how I could find the number.

Comment: Doesn't exist. $\ln n$ grows slower than any power $n^{\varepsilon}$ with $\varepsilon > 0$.

Comment: Show $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\ln(n)/n^k)=0$ $\forall$ $k>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on $n>1$ the number $k=k_n=\frac{ln(ln(n))}{ln(n)}$ will solve this equation, but it depends on $n$. As Daniel mentioned, there is no $k$, that solves the equation simultaneously for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.